# How to stop create in rails 5 without rolling back changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to check if a similar record exist in database before save, if true then update the existing record without saving, else create a new one

In rails 5:
returning false in a hook method doesn't halt callbacks and "throw :abort" is used instead.

the problem is using "throw :abort" rolls back any changes made in the before_save callback.

what I am trying to do is to check for a similar recored in "before_save" and if a similar record exist I need to update the current record and stop saving the new one.

I used

```
before_save :check
def check
    if (similar record exist..)
       update current...
       return false <==========
    end
    true
end
```

but this is not working any more in Rails 5 so returning false doesn't stop it from saving the new record too.

and I tried

```
before_save :check
def check
    if (exist..)
       update current...
       throw :abort <========
    end
    true
end
```

this stops saving current record to db but it perform "rollback" so the updated recored is missed !!

how can I do that ?

Comment: What does "similar record" exist? E.g., you've determined you cannot use `create_or_update` (or whatever it is)? In any case, I think a `before_save` is kind of counter-intuitive for this usecase, and shouldn't be handled in a callback.

Comment: I just though that `create_or_update` will not prevent others from using `create` explicitly

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you mean: "I need to check if a similar record exist in database before save, if true then update the existing record without saving, else create a new one."?

Comment: Yes I mean that, sorry for misunderstanding, I updated the question @iGian

Comment: Can you just create the new record, then use `after_create` to check if there is a "similar record", in case copy the value to the older and delete the actual (`self.delete`)?

Comment: @hassanalmorsy It wouldn't, although you could just override `create`, because programming.

Comment: I didn't want to user `after_create` to avoid wasting the time of inserting and then deleting and updating. @iGian

Comment: @Dave Newton, I want to avoid overriding to avoid any possible problems or conflicts.

Comment: Instead of running this as callback in the model itself, why not use [`#find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) or [`#find_or_initialize_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by) when instantiating the instance?

Comment: ... Those are conflicting requirements.

Comment: Using the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach you could take:

Instead of using `before_save`, create your own validation and use `assign_attributes` instead of `update` or `create` since `assign_attributes` won't actually write to the database. You could then call the `valid?` function on your record to execute your validations. If you get a duplicate record error from the validation you defined, then have your code handle updating the existing record in the logic of your error handling.

Something like this in your controller:

```
@record.assign_attributes(my_parameter: params[:my_parameter])
if @record.valid?
   @record.save
else
    puts @record.errors.messages.inspect
    #update your existing record instead. 
end
```

Then in your model:

```
validate :my_validation

def my_validation
   if record_already_exists
       return errors.add :base, "Your custom error message here." 
   end
end
```

Comment: This not entirely valid, [`#update_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) is just an alias for `#update`. I guess you meant to call [`#assign_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes). However `#assign_attributes` doesn't trigger validations, you'll have to do this manually using the [`#valid?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) method.

Comment: I just don't want others to be able to call `create` explicitly

Comment: @JohanWentholt Thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is one possible way. This example if with a `Product` model looking for same `name`.

```
  before_create :rollback_if_similar_exists
  after_rollback :update_existing_record

  def rollback_if_similar_exists
    throw :abort if Product.exists? name: self.name
  end

  def update_existing_record
    # do here what you need
    puts name
    puts "find the existing record"
    puts "update data"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [`#find_or_initialize_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by) or [`#find_or_create_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) to instantiate your instances. Instead of placing record swapping code inside a callback. This means you'll do something like this (example controller create):

```
class Post < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find_or_initialize_by(title: param[:title])

    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

Pair this with a validation that doesn't allow you to create double records with similar attributes and you're set.

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title, null: false
  t.text   :body
end
add_index :posts, :title, unique: true
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

---

**I don't recommend the following code**, but you could set the *id* of your instance to match the record with similar data. However you'll have to bypass persistence (keeps track of new and persistent records) and dirty (keeps track of attribute changes). Otherwise you'll create a new record or update the current id instead of the similar record id:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :set_similar_id

  private

  def set_similar_id
    similar_record = Post.find_by(title: title)
    return unless similar_record

    @attributes['id'].instance_variable_set :@value, similar_record.id
    @new_record = false
  end

end
```

Keep in mind that only changes are submitted to the database when creating a new record. For new records these are only the attributes of which the attributes are set, attributes with value `nil` are not submitted and will keep their old value.

For existing records theses are the attributes that are not the same as there older variant and the rule `old_value != new_value` (not actual variable names) applies.